# Creating a JSON object and send it to PHP(server)

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to create a nested JSON object similar to the below one.

```
{
"Gender":{
  "male":"yes",
      "female":"yes",
   },
   "Role":{

     "RoleA":"yes",
     "RoleB":"yes"
  },
[…]
}
```

Tried below code but,I am able to insert only one key-value pair.

```
JsonObject innerObject = new JsonObject();
innerObject.addProperty("Male", "yes");
innerObject.addProperty("Female", "yes");

JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.add("Gender", innerObject);
```

The above code would just create the Gender array. How do I create the entire array (as mentioned above)?

Comment: if you are using jquery you can work with a generated string using http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why work with JSON directly? JSON's an encoding/transport format, not something you ever work with directly. Just create a native data structure in whatever language you're working when, then use that language's equivalent of `json_encode()` to do the translation for you.

Since you've tagged this PHP, why not just

```
$data = array(
   'Gender' => array('male' => 'yes', 'female' => 'yes'),
   'Role' => array(etc...etc...),
    etc...etc...
);
echo json_encode($data);
```

Poof. One JSON-encoded "object".

Comment: Thanks alot marc.How to achieve the above logic via JS?Because I am sending the data via JS to PHP(Server).

Comment: `var data = {{'gender':{'male':'yes', etc...}}`. JSON - **JAVASCRIPT** object notation. Basically JSON text is the right-hand side of a JS variable assignment. `var foo = json_text_goes_here` (with a few restrictions).

Comment: Once you've got your javascript data structure, then JSON it with `JSON.stringify()`.

Comment: Finally:var jsonData = {{'gender':{'male':'yes','female':'yes'}}};JSON.stringify(jsonData);

Comment: Hey thanks marc.Now I am ready to send my data in JSON format to server(PHP).How to retreive it on server via PHP?Because for now,I am retreiving data via POST.So,is there anything that I have to perform on server to read the data on server?

Comment: use an ajax call? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ wouldn't even have to do the json.stringify business, just pass in your data array variable and jquery will handle it all for you.

Comment: yes I would be using AJAX to send the data to the server.But at the server end,how should I be retreiving the JSON Data?Sorry for my ignorance.I am completely new.

Comment: it'll come in as a normal form submission, then you just have `$php_array = json_decode($_POST['formfieldname'])`.

Comment: Sure.Thanks alot marc.You really helped me.A big +1 :)